# Sumar valores javascript

Tags: javascript, php

estoy intentando sumar los valores de los inputs pero no me aparece el resultado correctamente.

**PHP**

```
    for ($l = 0; $l < 5; $l++) {

    <input type='number' onchange='sumar_fase($l);' id='fase_lunes_$l' name='fase_lunes_$l' 
     value='0'>
    }
```

**JS**

```
function sumar_fase(l){
  var total_suma = document.getElementsByClassName('suma').length;
  console.log(total_suma);
  var total=0;
  for(i=0;i<=total_suma;i++){
   var fases = document.getElementById('tr_fase_lunes_'+i);
   total +=parseInt(fases.value);
}
document.getElementById('fase_total_lunes').value = total;
}
</script>
```

Comment: No entiendo donde quieres sumar

Comment: Son 5 inputs de tipo número, y quiero que se sumen segun el valor del input, es decir si yo pongo en el input 1 de valor 2 y en el input 2 de valor 3 que en el total me saque de valor 5 porque 3+2+0+0+0 = 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo tu código modificado.

Arreglado:

-Contador de todos los inputs con la clase **suma** para saber la cantidad.

-Valor total cambiado por **+=** en vez de **=** para que sume y no reemplaze.

-Agregué label *fase_total_lunes* para mostrar el total.

---

```js
 function sumar_fase(l){
 var total_suma = document.getElementsByClassName("suma").length;
 var total=0;
 for(i=1;i<=total_suma;i++)
 {
  var fases = document.getElementById('fase_lunes_'+i);
  total +=parseInt(fases.value);
 }
 alert("El valor es " + total);
 document.getElementById('fase_total_lunes').innerHTML = total;
}
```

```html
<input type='number' class='suma' onchange='sumar_fase(1);' id='fase_lunes_1' name='fase_lunes_1' 
 value='0'><br>
 <input type='number' class='suma' onchange='sumar_fase(2);' id='fase_lunes_2' name='fase_lunes_2' 
 value='0'><br>
 <input type='number' class='suma' onchange='sumar_fase(3);' id='fase_lunes_3' name='fase_lunes_3' 
 value='0'><br>
 
 <br>
 <label id="fase_total_lunes"></label>
```

Comment: Pero ahi si en el mismo input pongo un valor de 1 primero y luego le pongo un valor de 2, me saca 3 y deberia sacar 2.

Comment: Si te fijas al poner un 2 en el primer input te saca de valor 3.

Comment: Tal y como dice Luis tu variable total no se resetea correctamente. Corrige eso.

Comment: @Luis  1 + 2 = 2 ? entonces no entendi lo que deseas jajaja explicame para ayudarte, para modificar la respuesta

Comment: @josueVargas si te das cuenta cuando ejecutas tu codigo el input 1 --> VALOR 1, posteriormente le añades un valor al input 1 de 2 y te suma 3, por tanto no esta cogiendo bien el valor del input 1, deberia sacarte 2 como valor del input 1 no 3, --> lo puedes comprobar añadiendo un 2 al input 1 verás como de resultado te da 3 y deberia darte 2

Comment: @JosueVargas lo puedes comprobar añadiendo un 2 al input 1 verás como de resultado te da 3 y deberia darte 2

Comment: @Luis ahhh ya te entendí, disculpa no captaba la idea, ya te actualice la respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Coloca tu código aca https://jsfiddle.net/ de igual manera te dejo este código para que edites allí y así ayudarte mejor https://jsfiddle.net/45jkyamq/